# How to Filter Excel Sheet with 2 Columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have data coming from a query. I would like to filter data certain data based on parameters in two different columns.

[image]

I would like to write a macro, or maybe there's an excel function, that will allow me to filter out data point that contains "PUT" in the column PRI_GRP_CD and "FLOOR" in the column SCNDY_GRP_CD. It must contain both. I know there are ways to sort the data, but I want to hide all of the other data points that don't contain aforementioned criteria. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you add a helper column? If so, use a helper column that just concatenates the two into one, and sort on that?

Answer (score 0):

The code below assumes that your **PRI_GRP_CD** column is column **E** and simply hides the entire row from view.

```
Sub HideData()

Dim xlRange As Range
Dim xlCell As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set xlRange = Range(Range("E2"), Range("E2").End(xlDown))
    For Each xlCell In xlRange
        If Not (xlCell.Value = "PUT" And xlCell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "FLOOR") Then
            xlCell.EntireRow.Hidden = True
        End If
    Next xlCell
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```